# How to get event target without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to get the target (`<li>` element) from the **mouseenter** event but so far no luck!

The code:

```
<ul id="ul">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>

<script>
    var ul = document.getElementById('ul');

    ul.onmouseenter = function(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
    };
</script>
```

Unfortunately the console keeps printing the `<ul />` element. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the `onmouseenter` event is not a "bubbling" event, so it only fires when you enter the `UL` element, not when you enter nested elements, like the `LI` elements.

Therefore the `e.target` and the `this` elements will both be the `UL`.

If you use `onmouseover` instead it'll bubble, so you'll get the `LI` as the `e.target` when entering the `LI` elements.

Comment: Yeah this was my hunch but just thought I'd ask anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the targeted li like:

```
function getEventTarget(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    return e.target || e.srcElement; 
}

var ul = document.getElementById('ul');
ul.onclick= function(event) {
    var target = getEventTarget(event);
    console.log(target.innerHTML);
};
```

Comment: For working example follow the link. [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vikashh/WTM27/)

Comment: @VikashPathak thanks for the sample code, but I'm actually specifically asking for the mouseenter event ;)

Comment: @smaili—maybe, but if you ignore the IE event model and `event.srcElement` your code will fail in some browsers in use.